# Basic python 3 encryption, mostly involving ord() function

Tags: python, python-3.x, encryption

This functions takes a word, makes it lowercase, and then encrypts it by switching around the letters. 'Cat' should return 'yug', 'dog' should return 'awg', 'zeal' should return 'scug', 'Cool' should return 'ywwg'

```
def doppelt(word):

    new_ord = word.lower()
    encoded = ''
    for c in word:
            new_ord = ord(c)
            new_ord = 96 + (new_ord - 120) % 26
            encoded += chr(new_ord)
    return encoded.lower()
```

The output of doppelt('Cat') is 'ycv'. What am I doing wrong? I know it's involving the 96 + (new_ord - 120) % 26 line, but I can't seem to get any combination to work properly.

Comment: Could you explain how the letters are supposed to be switched around? Why does `c` become `y` but `a` becomes `u`?

Comment: Since capitol letters have a different ord() value than lowercase letters, the 'C' in cat has a different value than a lowercase 'c', which is 99. The ord() value for 'C' is 67, therefore the encryption comes out differently.

Comment: @yungdaggerd but it looks like you're trying to lowercase the string before encrypting it, and if you're not then your search space is too small (you're only doing mod 26!)

Comment: 'Cat' -> 'yug'  and 'dog' -> 'awg' and 'zeal' -> 'scug'.... so  t, g, l all  map to g?

Comment: You still need to explain the encryption algorithm you're trying to implement. Your examples aren't a simple Caesar cipher, so what is it?

Comment: @wim Apparently the last character always becomes `g` :)

Comment: Apparently. I just noticed that. Thats some next level observation skills.

Comment: @barmar These are the only examples provided on the problem I am working on. The goal is to mimic the examples and return the output in all lowercase.

Comment: @yungdaggerd sounds like you need clarification from your instructor then. Good luck!

Comment: @yungdaggerd The problem statement needs to explain the algorithm you're supposed to implement. You can't derive the full algorithm from just these 3 examples, there's no obvious pattern to them.

Comment: Agreed with @Barmar. From your current examples the best anyone could do is `{"cat":"yug", "dog": "awg", "zeal": "scug", "cool": "ywwg"}.get(word.lower())`